# While Sending Data To Google Power Meter Results Error PM-404-0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

i am trying to sent data to google power meter it gives me error my code is post on the link below i ask question before but now i am also pasting the exact error i am getting on this post at the bottom

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425107/pm-404-0-not-found

the output error is,

```
MeterValue : 3026.34666533831
Requesting...Result : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><atom:feed xmlns:ato
m='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearc
hrss/1.0/' xmlns:meter='http://schemas.google.com/meter/2008' xmlns:batch='http:
//schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'><atom:id>https://www.google.com/powermeter/fee
ds/event//1308804739808</atom:id><atom:updated>2011-06-23T04:52:19.918Z</atom:up
dated><atom:title type='text'>Batch Feed</atom:title><atom:entry><atom:updated>2
011-06-23T04:52:19.918Z</atom:updated><atom:title type='text'>Error</atom:title>
<atom:content type='text'>PM404-0: Not found</atom:content><batch:status code='4
04' reason='PM404-0: Not found' content-type='text/plain'>PM404-0: Not found</ba
tch:status></atom:entry></atom:feed>
```

Hopes for your Seggestions

Regards.

Comment: Please take care formatting your code. It makes more sense to edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425107/pm-404-0-not-found)